# NLP libraries for simple POS tagging

Tags: c, nlp, artificial-intelligence, tagging

I'm a student who's working on a summer project in NLP.  I'm fairly new to the field, so I apologize if there's a really obvious solution.  The project is in C, both due to my familiarity with it, and the computationally intensive nature of the project (my corpus is a plaintext dump of wikipedia).

I'm working on an approach to relationship extraction, exploiting the consistency principle to try to learn (to within some error threshold) a set of rules dictating which clusters of grammar objects imply a connection between those objects.

One of the first steps in the algorithm involves finding the set of all possible grammar objects a given word can refer to (POS disambiguation is done implicitly by the algorithm at a later step).  I've looked at several parsers, but they all seem to do the disambiguation step themselves, which (from my end) is counterproductive.  I'm looking for something off the shelf that (ideally) gives me a one-command way to turn up this information.

Does such a thing exist?  If not, is there an existent dictionary containing this information that's trivially machine parseable?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you want to roll your own pos tagger as part of a joint pos-tagging and something-else task, rather than using an existing pos tagger or even an existing parser as an input to your relationship extraction system?  Why reinvent every wheel all at once?  Why not try the relationship extraction task by e.g. applying your methods to rerank an existing relationship extractor, or by starting with best-k dependency parses, and only later go into fixing the lower parts or doing joint inference?

Comment: That might actually be harder.  With the algorithm I'm using, in principle, you should get POS tagging basically for free, as a side effect of some other processes.  

I'm going to be straight with you: I don't really know what I'm doing.  The algorithm literally came to me in a dream a couple of weeks ago, after a late night reading a book on information theory.  I'm less interested in getting a functioning parser than seeing if the algorithm actually performs above chance level.  To that end, implementing a quick and dirty (<5k) version of the algorithm seems like a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Look at CMU Sphinx. An open source NLP project. I think its in C++ but you can integrate it or at least get the idea of how to go about things.

Answer (score 0):

What about calling an external POS tagger as a shell script or wrapping it in an http service if you feel frisky?

Java and Python have the vast majority of NLP libraries so it makes sense to take advantage of that. If you can use NLTK in a script to tag stuff, call this script from C, that makes it much easier.